# Compare Two Arrays in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, api

I'm trying to compare two array values in laravel blade view. one of array is calling from a API. one of array is calling from database. So I want to match NIC number in both array.

I tried to do it by nested loop. When I do it, Browser getting 500 error.

My Controller is as follows :

```
 public function match_nic(){

     $url = 'https://www.becsystems.org/BSS/Api_Controller/index';

      $options = array('http' => array(
          'method'  => 'GET',
      ));
      $context  = stream_context_create($options);
      $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

      $api_youths = json_decode($response);

      $database_youths = DB::table('youths')->get();

      return view('youths')->with(['api_youths'=> $api_youths, 'database_youths' => $database_youths]);

 }
```

My Blade view is as follows

```
          @foreach($database_youths as $d_youth)
              @foreach($api_youths as $a_youth)
                  @if($a_youth->nic == $d_youth->nic)
                      {{$d_youth->nic}}
                  @else
                      {{'Not Matched'}}
                  @endif
              @endforeach
          @endforeach
```

When I run the page I'm getting

[image]

How  Can I fix this.

Comment: please enable debug and share the error details

Comment: Taken a look at your Laravel log to see what the error is?

Comment: As well, doing the comparison logic in your view seems like a bad Idea.. You should do it in your controller or your model

Comment: On a side note `$api_youths` is an array and in your blade you are calling it as an object.. You will get a `trying to get property of a non-object error`

Comment: Hi Christophe Hubert : ``Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes)``

Comment: HI Kerbholz : ``Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes)``

Comment: Well, your API doesn't have pagination and it's too massive to process for your server...

Comment: Hi How can I paginate it  in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach your problem:

1. Get the list of all the NIC from your `$api_youths` array to `$nics = ['nic1', 'nic2', ...]`. You can use the following code for this purpose:

```
$nics = Arr::pluck($api_youths, 'nic');
```

2. Get the list of database items that have those NIC `$matched_nics = DB::table('youths')->whereIn('nic', $nics);
3. Get the list of database items that don't have those NIC `$unmatched_nics = DB::table('youths')->whereNotIn('nic', $nics)`;
4. Display the result in your blade.

Comment: Thanks Bro. How can I do Number 1 ?

Comment: it will depend on the format of your `$api_youths` if you can share an example it would help

Comment: Thanks Bro. I did it using ``array_column`` function, But I need to get associated name with NIC also. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please share an example of your $api_youths PHP array

Comment: [Click Here to see the array](https://bec.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/youth-placed-in-jobs)

Comment: I can't access the page, please add it to your question

Comment: [0=> {'id':1,"nic": "2555578V","Status":"on the job"} , 1=> {'id':2,"nic": "5679874V","Status":"studying"}]

Comment: Please provide a valid PHP array and add it to the question, not a comment 

Comment: And you can check my updated answer that should help you